# Regex to match multiple white spaces until one character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will detect markdown quoting blocks.
Here is my regex so far:

```
(?:^|\n)[ \t]*(>[ \t]*\S(?:(?!\n(\s*\n)+[^>])[\s\S])*)

(?:^|\n)            beginning of string, or a line break
[ \t]*              optional spaces
>[ \t]*\S           `>` followed by optional spaces and at least one character
( ... [\s\S])*      capture any following character\white-space multiple times
(?!\n(\s*\n)+[^>])  stop capture if next following characters are
                    at least 2 line breaks mixed with other white-spaces
                    followed by anything but `>`
```

Everything works fine, except for the negative lookahead: the capture stops if more than 2 line breaks are encountered.

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qG9mE9) shows me 4 matches when I want 3. Any pointers?

Comment: Your description of your regex doesn't match the actual regex.  Specifically that last line in the description has a `+` that is not present in the actual regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is here:

```
(?!\n(\s*\n)+[^>])
```

The `[^>]` is matching a `\n`.  Change it to this:

```
(?!\n(\s*\n)+[^>\s])
```

http://regex101.com/r/mT4wC4